# Null children subcategories or db definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to develop a very simple ASP.net core 2.0 web API. It contains two model classes: Categories and Subcategories. However, when I call the CategoriesController as:

http://localhost:51242/api/categories

... all children Subcategories are null.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "en":"Sports",
      "de":"Sports",
      "fr":"Sports",
      "it":"Sport",
      "es":"Deportes",
      "shown":0,
      "subcategories":null,
      "subscribers":0
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "en":"Computers",
      "de":"Computers",
      "fr":"Computers",
      "it":"Computers",
      "es":"Computadoras",
      "shown":0,
      "subcategories":null,
      "subscribers":0
   }
]
```

When I seed to DB (UseInMemoryDatabase), I see that the DbSet Categories contains all subcategories present in the json file used for seeding (see image). So I am not sure what is it happening? Did I miss something?

[image: Screenshot after seeding the DB]

I am new to ASP.net core, this is my first application :-)

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Categories")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly NetAdContext _context;

    public CategoriesController(NetAdContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Categories
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return _context.Categories;
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string En { get; set; }
    public string De { get; set; }
    public string Fr { get; set; }
    public string It { get; set; }
    public string Es { get; set; }
    public long Shown { get; set; }
    public List<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
}

public class Subcategory
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string En { get; set; }
    public string De { get; set; }
    public string Fr { get; set; }
    public string It { get; set; }
    public string Es { get; set; }
    public long Shown { get; set; }
    public long Subscribers { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public long LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

NetAdSeed is called from Program.cs

```
static public class NetAdSeed
{
    public static void Initialize(NetAdContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Seed categories and subcategories
        if (context.Categories.Count() == 0)
        {
            // Load list of categories and subcategories from file to string
            string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\json\categories.json");

            // Deserialize
            List<Category> cats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(json);

            context.Categories.AddRange(cats);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class NetAdContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Subcategory> Subcategory { get; set; }

    public NetAdContext(DbContextOptions<NetAdContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code has many issues:

```
// GET: api/Categories
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
{
    return _context.Categories;
}
```

- Database requests should be asynchronous, specially with Entity Framework Core that supports this out of the box.
- You should always return `IActionResult` in ASP.NET Core, so you can return different results and keep it agnostic of the result
- You should not return entities directly, instead, Data Transfer Objects should be used. This allows you to change what you return according to the client

So, this should look something like this:

```
public class CategoryDto // or some other better name
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Choose the MINIMUM amount of properties that the client needs
}

// GET: api/Categories
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategories()
{
    var categories = await _context.Categories
        .Include(x => x.SubCategories) // this line you are missing
        .ToListAsync();

    return Ok(categories);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I will follow your suggestions. My code for GetCategories() is the one that is automatically generated by scaffolding.

Comment: @goicox Yeah, I figured. The scaffolder is not the best, unfortunately. You are welcome, glad to help. Let me know how it works

Comment: Your GetCategories() implementation works!! Thank you

Comment: @goicox Glad to hear that, you may want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Now, if I want to return only one category given its id: // GET: api/Categories/5. How should I include the subcategories?

Comment: @goicox Same story, add `.Include(x => x.SubCategories)` to the query, as I did in the answer. It can be before or after the `.Where()` call